# Why didn’t the pills Brandon was taking have a letter on the back?

Tags: analysis, house

House MD: S1,E3

Once Brandon is treated for colchicine poisoning, he is prescribed new cough medicines before being discharged from the hospital. He surprisingly remarks

> There’s a letter on the back of these pills.

His old pills didn’t have a letter on them. Why ? Because he did see a doctor before who prescribed him cough medication. What went wrong and where?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, he was *prescribed* the correct medication but given a different drug by the pharmacist where the pills **looked the same** as the pills he should have been given but were, in fact, for a different drug.

Comment: Doesn’t make it clear. When Chase went to the pharmacy, the pharmacist was pretty sure he’d given the correct pills. But both Chase and Cameron were surprised when Brandon said that the pills he was taking earlier had no letter. And then the ending shows House searching for pills in the hospital pharmacy and finds both kind of pills, with and without the letter.

Comment: He finds pills that look the same but are different drugs. That's the point.